# Minimizing f(x) when f(x) can only be probed via a random process

Tags: optimization, random-variables

Background: I'm writing a piece of software to run on a mid-tier HPC cluster, to perform automatic parameter optimization.

Say I have a function f(x).  I need to find x that minimizes f(x).  For our purposes we shall consider f(x) to be an unknown, smooth, concave-up function of one variable.  In reality it might not be so good and I will probably have to write a hyperdimensional implementation, but for the question let's consider one dimension.  Normally I would just use Newton's method or something similar, but there's a catch here: I cannot actually evaluate f(x).  Instead, I must probe f(x) via a process that returns a value pulled from a [assumed to be normal] distribution.  Additionally, every probe has a real and significant cost, say one CPU*hour, so I need a maximally probe-efficient implementation.  The one advantage I have is that x is bounded -- a<x<b, for supplied a and b.

My idea was to linearly interpolate between points: start by sampling at x=a and x=b, and x=(a+b)/2 (possibly more, in practice I will get more than one sample in parallel).  Then, using some kind of interpolation I would "guess" at which side is better for my next test.  Here's the hard part: I would like to probe the location of minimal expectation-3 standard deviations. (That is, it will test areas with either high uncertainty:filling in the gaps--and areas of low value: searching for the goal).  I really have no idea how to get an expected standard deviation of points that are at varying values of x though, and doing each probe enough times to get a usable standard deviation at every point is far too expensive.  I was considering doing a local least-squares fit to a quadratic about the test-point and using the deviation from that or something, but I'm really not sure if/how well that will work, or if repeatedly doing this will be too expensive.  I can afford quite a long time (figure seconds of compute time) deciding where to probe next, but not *that* long.

Any ideas on either how to predict the value and error of an interpolated value, or about a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

I would refer you to [stochastic optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization), it deals with just this issue. Lots of approaches to consider.